# How would one check the system memory available using R on a Windows machine?

Tags: r, windows, memory

I am running a multi-threaded R program but am having trouble with some nodes crashing due to the host system running out of memory. Is there a way for each node to check the available memory for the entire system before continuing to run? (machine is running Windows Server 2012 R2)

Comment: I'm almost certain I answered that one before.

Comment: I've looked pretty exhaustively throughout StackOverflow without finding any answer. There are a lot of solutions showing memory usage within the R session, but nothing showing information about the memory of the actual system.

Comment: The problem with this is that is very OS specific. On Linux you could call system() or pipe() and massage the output of free() accordingly.

Comment: I'm working on a Windows machine, I'll update the question to reflect that.

Comment: Hm, there may be other command-line tools you could query -- but I am less familiar with that platform.  Parallel programming may  generally be a little easier on a Unix-based system.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe one of the below will help ( I am also on Windows Server 2012 R2):

Maybe this would be the most useful:

```
> system('systeminfo')
#the output is too big to show but you can save into a list and choose the rows you want
```

Or just use one of the below which are specific about the memory

```
> system('wmic MemoryChip get BankLabel, Capacity, MemoryType, TypeDetail, Speed')
BankLabel    Capacity    MemoryType  Speed  TypeDetail  
RAM slot #0  8589934592  2                  512         
RAM slot #1  4294967296  2                  512
```

Free available memory:

```
> system('wmic OS get FreePhysicalMemory /Value')
FreePhysicalMemory=8044340
```

Total available Memory

```
> system('wmic OS get TotalVisibleMemorySize /Value')
TotalVisibleMemorySize=12582456
```

Basically you can even run any other cmd command you want that you know it could help you through the `system` function. R will show the output on the screen and you can then save into a data.frame and use as you want.

Comment: This is perfect thank you. I did some output alteration to have it return the free memory in GB.
`as.numeric(gsub("\r","",gsub("FreePhysicalMemory=","",system('wmic OS get FreePhysicalMemory /Value',intern=TRUE)[3])))/1024/1024
[1] 2.90044`

Answer (score 6):

Just for the sake of completion, I added support for Linux on Stefan's answer above-
Tested on Ubuntu 16

```
getFreeMemoryKB <- function() {
  osName <- Sys.info()[["sysname"]]
  if (osName == "Windows") {
    x <- system2("wmic", args =  "OS get FreePhysicalMemory /Value", stdout = TRUE)
    x <- x[grepl("FreePhysicalMemory", x)]
    x <- gsub("FreePhysicalMemory=", "", x, fixed = TRUE)
    x <- gsub("\r", "", x, fixed = TRUE)
    return(as.integer(x))
  } else if (osName == 'Linux') {
    x <- system2('free', args='-k', stdout=TRUE)
    x <- strsplit(x[2], " +")[[1]][4]
    return(as.integer(x))
  } else {
    stop("Only supported on Windows and Linux")
  }
}
```

Comment: I think that for Linux argument for command `free` should be `--kilo` and not `-k`. From `free --help`:
`--kilo          show output in kilobytes` and `-k, --kibi          show output in kibibytes`

Answer (score 5):

I wrapped LyzandeR's answer above up in a functions that returns the physical memory in kilobytes (1024 bytes). Tested on windows 7.

```
get_free_ram <- function(){
  if(Sys.info()[["sysname"]] == "Windows"){
    x <- system2("wmic", args =  "OS get FreePhysicalMemory /Value", stdout = TRUE)
    x <- x[grepl("FreePhysicalMemory", x)]
    x <- gsub("FreePhysicalMemory=", "", x, fixed = TRUE)
    x <- gsub("\r", "", x, fixed = TRUE)
    as.integer(x)
  } else {
    stop("Only supported on Windows OS")
  }
}
```