# Speeding up apply UDF, and R

Tags: r, performance, function, apply

I have some large data frames that I have to work with (>100GB each). I need the output like this (`adherence$adherence`):

```
 adherence <- cbind.data.frame(c("1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3"), c("2013.1", "2013.1", "2013.1", "2013.2", "2013.2", "2013.2"))
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
names(adherence)[1] <- "ID" 
names(adherence)[2] <- "year"
adherence$year <- as.numeric(as.character(adherence$year))

lsr <- cbind.data.frame(
  c("1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3"), #ID
  c("2012.3", "2012.8", "2013.1","2012.8", "2013.3", "2013.9", "2011", "2013"), #eksd
  c("60", "90", "90", "60", "120", "60", "30", "90") # DDD
)
names(lsr)[1] <- "ID"
names(lsr)[2] <- "eksd"
names(lsr)[3] <- "DDD"

lsr$eksd <- as.numeric(as.character(lsr$eksd))
lsr$DDD <- as.numeric(as.character(lsr$DDD))
lsr$ENDDATE <- lsr$eksd + lsr$DDD/365.25


adherence <- adherence %>% full_join(lsr, by = 'ID')  %>% mutate(newVariable = ifelse(eksd <= year & year <= ENDDATE, (ENDDATE - year) * 365.25, 0)) %>% 
  group_by(ID, year) %>% summarize(newVariable = sum(newVariable)) 

function.AH <- function(x) {
  A <- subset(lsr, ID == x[1] & eksd <= x[2] & ENDDATE > x[2]) 
  ifelse(nrow(A) == 0, 0, sum(A$ENDDATE-as.numeric(x[2]))*365.25)
   }

adherence$AH <-apply (adherence, 1,  FUN = function.AH)
```

`Adherence$adherence` and `adherence$AH` are two ways to achieve the same output.
The first way using the `full_join` won't run, obviously because it expands the data frame into the billions of rows, and can't keep it in the RAM. The second version runs but it's still running (about one week now) and I need to do this quite some times.

I've been looking into different ways to improve the efficiency; using parallel processing won't work as I can only access one CPU on the server; switching `if` function with `ifelse`. Another thing I found (or as I understood it) was that apparently the data frame `lsr` is converted and copied into a matrix and copied several times during the function for each row of the adherence dataset of which I have about 6000, if so this would explain a lot of the long run time.

I've been keeping my data in the data.frame format, should I choose something else (e.g., `data.table`) as suggested [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/strategies-to-speedup-r-code/)?

If so would you choose to change your data structure all the way through all other analyses or just around this part that I've shown?

Sorry about the all the questions, I just want to show that I have thought about it a lot. Basically, I'm just asking: how do I make this function.AH run as fast as possible?

Comment: If you have just one ~100GB data frame, you need a system with 128GB of RAM just to read that in. Do you have such a system? To do any real operations on even that one, general guidance is to have at least 2x RAM, so really 256 GB. To use both data frames together would mean over 512 GB of RAM.  Also: you should include some further explanation of the process(es) you need to perform as well as code since that's likely to garner more attention and aid. If this is literally a "do a left join" then move the data into PostgreSQL & use postgres dplyr back-end to let it do the work out of RAM.

Comment: I stopped the operation to check for RAM (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27788968/how-would-one-check-the-system-memory-available-using-r-on-a-windows-machine) 
but I couldn't get it to work. 
I'm pretty sure I could avoid having more than one data frame open at any time by adding some extra steps, if that could speed up things. It does take a long time maybe 5-7 hours to open into the environment :-)  Maybe it wasn't clear but I want to apply the function.AH over every row in the adherence data frame resulting in a vector of adherence$adherence. Or do I misunderstand "further explain"

Comment: data frames are rectangular data structures. database tables are rectangular data structures. R's `dplyr` package (& helpers) can do operations in-database vs in-R. So the operation can be done all on the DB side. You should know if your system has 128GB of RAM or more w/o having to stop R ops, too.

Comment: The server is accessed via VPN to a very restricted environment with the national statistics bureaus servers so I thought that I had to stop ops to answer the question via R studio. Any way you mention something like this: https://datascienceplus.com/working-with-databases-in-r/ and I think that may help speed up the analysis. I'll try at least.